# angular 6 array to JSON for spring backend

Tags: java, json, angular6

I have a Java backend that accepts a json response like this:

{
        "accounts": [{
          "t1_Title": "title1"
        }, {
          "t1_Title": "title2"
        }]
     }

In Angular i send an array to a service to be sent to the backend.
How do i add "accounts" to an array and keep the structure above from the array which is structured like this:

```
    (2) [Array(1), Array(1)]
     0: [{…}]
     1: [{…}]
     length: 2
```

Comment: Just do `{accounts : myArray}` and then send to back end. Whats your problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind the array value to `accounts` key within a new object.

Example code :

```js
let myArray = [{ "t1_Title": "title1" }, { "t1_Title": "title2" }]

//build JSON
let obj = {accounts : myArray};

// print JSON
console.log(obj)
```